# Linux: "Password reset by root is not supported"...so how do I reset passwords?

Tags: linux, passwords, password-management

I'm a "backup" sysadmin for a small team, and the primary sysadmin is unavailable.  The lab setup is a little bit new to me, and I'm not familiar with everything about how it's setup yet (and my Linux sysadmin skills are probably a little out of date).  I was asked to reset a password for a user, and I thought "great, that's just passwd -e username".  Unfortunately, this gives me:

```
# /usr/bin/passwd jdoe
Changing password for user jdoe.
Password reset by root is not supported.
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

At first I thought I just need to use `ldappasswd` instead, but apparently it's not using LDAP (`/usr/bin/ldappasswd` does not exist and the command is not found on the system).  Finally, I checked `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and saw this:

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
```

Additional info: This system (and most of my lab network) is running on CentOS release 6.6.

Ok, I guess my Linux skills are a little bit inadequate or rusty.  What is "sss"?  And how do I accomplish a simple password reset on this system?

**Updated Information:**
I am attempting to reset the password as the root user (yeah, not the best security setup that we have root login enabled and not sudo for the lab admins, but I'm just the backup guy...I can only *try* to influence).  What appear to be the relevant lines from `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` are (best guess, as I said, I'm rusty on some things, like IPA):

```
ipa_domain = sub.domain.mycompany.com
id_provider = ipa
auth_provider = ipa
ldap_autofs_entry_object_class = automount
access_provider = ipa
ipa_hostname = node6.sub.domain.mycompany.com
chpass_provider = ipa
ldap_autofs_entry_key = automountKey
ipa_server = ipa1.sub.domain.mycompany.com, ipa2.sub.domain.mycompany.com
```

Comment: Was your username granted sudo rights?

Comment: Provide us the contents of nslcd.conf

Comment: Did you try `man sssd`? Do you have an `sssd.conf` file somewhere in `/etc`?

Comment: I can't find an nslcd.conf file, but I did post what appeared to be the relevant contents of the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file.  The server `ipa1` has all the expected LDAP commands installed, and I might be able to figure it out from here.  But I'll let one of you fine folks post an answer to claim credit if you wish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clues start with knowing that the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file on the system is used to configure the [Name Service Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) facility in Linux.  From wikipedia:

> The Name Service Switch (NSS) is a facility in Unix-like operating systems that provides a variety of sources for common configuration databases and name resolution mechanisms. These sources include local operating system files (such as /etc/passwd, /etc/group, and /etc/hosts), the Domain Name System (DNS), the Network Information Service (NIS), and LDAP.

This line from the [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) file lets us know that the Linux "System Security Services" (sss) is the provider for user passwords and related functions.

```
passwd:     files sss
```

The next clue comes from the contents of `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`.  [The man page for this configuration file](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd.conf) tells us about the `chpass_provider` entry, and for me that is ipa:

```
chpass_provider = ipa
```

And this line lets us know what server(s) are responsible for running the ipa services:

```
ipa_server = ipa1.sub.domain.mycompany.com, ipa2.sub.domain.mycompany.com
```

Finally, I just had to log on to `ipa1.sub.domain.mycompany.com`, where I see that `ipa` is indeed installed, as well as LDAP.  A couple judicious internet searches led me to this [Redhat page pertaining to managing passwords via IPA](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Identity_Management_Guide/changing-pwds.html), that gave me these helpful steps:

```
$ kinit admin
$ ipa user-mod jsmith --password
```

Voila, done!  Lesson learned: My lab system is kind of a hodge-podge of servers configured in a (perhaps) non-standard way, but a couple knowledgeable people can give you some clues to point you in the right direction, and following the bread crumbs and doing some Internet searches will hopefully reveal the answer.